# android seems not support statfs()

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, linux-kernel

I wanna check whether android  supporst the system-call,statfs().
So,i make the following code to check it(and it is compiled via ndk):

```
#include <sys/vfs.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct statfs diskInfo;
    statfs("/data",&diskInfo);
    perror("statfs,/data");
    unsigned long long blocksize = diskInfo.f_bsize;
    unsigned long long totalsize = blocksize * diskInfo.f_blocks;
    printf("new TOTAL_SIZE == %lu MB/n",totalsize>>20);
    unsigned long long freeDisk = diskInfo.f_bfree*blocksize;
    printf("DISK_FREE == %ld MB/n",freeDisk>>20);

 return 0;
}
```

And there is no error during compiling.But when it 's runned in the android emulator via adb,it prompt the following:

```
kaiwii@ubuntu:~$ adb shell /data/pwrite/test2
statfs,/data: No such file or directory
new TOTAL_SIZE == 0 MB/nDISK_FREE == 0 MB/n
```

Any idea?thx

Comment: Are you aware that Android provides a [Java wrapper for StatFS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html)? If that doesn't suit your needs, you might want to check out its implementation, although it'll probably do little more than wrapping the calls to the Unix command, as per description.

Comment: Yes.But,i need to use the systemcall,itself.

Comment: Well, are you sure you have a file or directory /data on the emulator? What happens if you try with just "/"?

Comment: of course.And i have also try the "/",but it also fails

Answer (score 0):

Actually, statfs is used in Android to discover the available space. As @MH pointed you the starting point is `StatFs.java` class. The implementation of native functions you can find in  `frameworks/base/core/jni/android_os_StatFs.cpp`. For instance, to get free blocks it implements the following function:

```
static jint
android_os_StatFs_getFreeBlocks(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz)
{
    struct statfs *stat = (struct statfs *)env->GetIntField(thiz, fields.context);
    return stat->f_bfree;
}
```

Thus, the problem is not that Android does not support `statfs` syscall, the problem is in your code. To my point of view, comparing with the code in `android_os_StatFs.cpp` you use wrong headers. In `android_os_StatFs.cpp` there are used the following headers:

```
#if INCLUDE_SYS_MOUNT_FOR_STATFS
#include <sys/mount.h>
#else
#include <sys/statfs.h>
#endif
```

Comment: ur analysis is very good.But,when i switch the headers into:#include <sys/statfs.h> #include <stdio.h>.the same error appear.Any more idea?thx

Comment: To my point of view, you should use <sys/mount.h> instead of <sys/statfs.h>.

Comment: Do not know, why this error happens. But try to use dynamic memory allocation for diskInfo. In android_os_StatFs.cpp they use dynamic allocation.

Comment: which method i can reffer to?i look through the whole android_os_StatFs.cpp,but can not find it.thx

Comment: Have a look at two methods that setup the environment: android_os_StatFs_native_setup and android_os_StatFs_native_restat.

Comment: Then you need to use c type of memory allocation and that's all.

Comment: jni/test2.c: In function 'main':
jni/test2.c:8: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc'
jni/test2.c:8: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct statfs' 
jni/test2.c:12: error: request for member 'f_bsize' in something not a structure or union
jni/test2.c:13: error: request for member 'f_blocks' in something not a structure or union
jni/test2.c:15: error: request for member 'f_bfree' in something not a structure or union
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/test2/test2.o] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem (statfs returns 0 bytes available). I fixed it replacing statfs(...) call by fstatfs(...). The following code works for me (tested on Android 4.2 and 5.0):

```
#include <sys/statfs.h>

typedef unsigned long long msize;
msize getAvailableDiskSpace() {
    struct statfs data;
    if (fstatfs(NULL, &data) < 0)
        return 0;
    return (msize)data.f_bsize * data.f_bfree;
}
```

Probably you also need to allow the acces to internal storage in the mainfest file (not sure, I did not check what happens if I remove the user permission).